pyarrow parquet does not round trip for a very simple example
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(data={'a':np.arange(100)}))

with open('example.parquet', 'wb') as f:
    pq.write_table(table, f) 

with open('example.parquet', 'rb') as ff:
    read_table = pq.read_table(ff)

then
table

returns
pyarrow.Table
a: int64
----
a: [[0,1,2,3,4,...,95,96,97,98,99]]

and
read_table

returns
pyarrow.Table
a: int64
----
a: [[0,1,2,3,4,...,95,96,97,98,99]]

but
table['a'].nbytes

is
800

and
read_table['a'].nbytes

is
813

The tables and their schemas both compare as equal.
How can I explain the discrepancy? The context is I am trying to compute a hash of two pyarrow tables, and that hash should be stable accross writing/reading to/from parquet.

Arrow doesn't guarantee that your data buffers will be bit-for-bit identical, especially when roundtripping through another format that wasn't necessarily designed with Arrow in mind. In this case, given that you have 100 8-byte integers, I'd guess that in-memory no validity bitmap was allocated but when decoding from Parquet, a validity bitmap was created (13 * 8 = 104).

thanks @li.davidm that makes sense - is there a different format that I could convert both tables to in which the above would be valid? Or is there an equivalent to pd.util.hash_pandas_object?

I don't think anything guarantees roundtrippability at this level. I think Arrow C++ has a hash function but AFAIK it isn't exposed to Python.

It's an optimization. 13 correspond to the size of the validity mask of the array. Because all the values are valid, one of the instance has omitted to store that array. read_table["a"].is_valid().nbytes == 13. You can look at the underlying buffers: read_table["a"].chunk(0).buffers() vs table["a"].chunk(0).buffers())
